# React fetching data from only one object? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map') TMDB API

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map the data of this api endpoint. It doesn't have a object name like results or something like that. So, what should I use to map that data?

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/10000?api_key=4f298a53e552283bee957836a529baec this is the endpoint that I am trying to use.

**this is the state management part, don't mind fetch part btw, I did some arrangements somewhere else to set that movieId;**

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState([]);

const searchById = (movieId) => {
    fetch(API_SEARCH_BY_ID + movieId + API_KEY)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setCurrent(data); 
        console.log(current);
        successAlert();
      });
  };
```

**This is the map function in my component file;**

```
<Container fluid>
        {current.map((current, currentReq) => (
          <MovieDetails current={current} key={currentReq.id} {...currentReq}></MovieDetails>
        ))}
</Container>
```

**This is the error I am getting;**

Details.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

**I am still in the learning phase of react, so I need some help here. Probably I am missing something silly here.**

**Thanks to DanPhilipBejoy, Answer is: generating a empty array named test and pushing the data into that array.**

```
const searchById = (movieId) => {
    fetch(API_SEARCH_BY_ID + movieId + API_KEY)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const test = [data]
        setCurrent(test); 
        successAlert();
      });
  };
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue? You haven't asked a question so far.

Comment: @DanPhilipBejoy normaly after fetching the data. I am using something like setCurrent(data.results) but in this json file. There isn't an array. This is just an object and I don't know how am I going to do the samething with this one. I tried to use Object.keys and it didn't work.

Comment: In this case its the data of a single movie, You either render the `MovieDetails` component outside a loop with the data you receive as prop, Or if you want to maintain this structure push the data you receive into an array and loop that array.

Comment: @DanPhilipBejoy Thank you, I will try this approach. Thanks btw, this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop if its just one element.

```
<Container fluid>
      <MovieDetails current={current} .../>
</Container>
```

OR

In case if you want to retain the JSX structure just do

```
setCurrent([data]);
```